# Query is taking a long time to execute

Tags: sql, sql-server

The query is taking too much time to execute. Ots comparing some condition and then fetching data accordingly.

Please guide me why its happening.

```
DECLARE @Rowcountcnzg int = 0;
DECLARE @countcnzg bigint = (SELECT CASE
                                         WHEN COUNT(*) >= 100000 THEN COUNT(*) / @BatchSize
                                         WHEN (COUNT(*) > 10000
                                           AND COUNT(*) < 100000) THEN COUNT(*) / 10000
                                         ELSE COUNT(*)
                                    END
                             FROM i_hold_sap_stock ss WITH (NOLOCK)
                                  JOIN tea_item ti ON ss.upload_tea_item = ti.tea_item
                                                  AND ss.upload_revision = ti.revision
                                  LEFT OUTER JOIN mdata_origin_channel_default_port ocdp1 ON ocdp1.origin = ti.origin
                                                                                         AND ocdp1.stock_type = ss.upload_stock_type
                                  LEFT OUTER JOIN mdata_origin_channel_default_port ocdp2 ON ocdp2.origin = ti.origin
                                                                                         AND ocdp2.stock_type = ''
                             WHERE Date_Loaded = @MaxDateLoaded
                               AND conv_zgport_ship = 'NULL');

WHILE (@Rowcountcnzg < @countcnzg + 1)
BEGIN
    UPDATE TOP (@BatchSize)
        ss
    SET conv_zgport_ship = ISNULL(ISNULL(ocdp1.default_origin_location, ocdp2.default_origin_location), 'NULL')
    FROM i_hold_sap_stock ss
         JOIN tea_item ti ON ss.upload_tea_item = ti.tea_item
                         AND ss.upload_revision = ti.revision
         LEFT OUTER JOIN mdata_origin_channel_default_port ocdp1 ON ocdp1.origin = ti.origin
                                                                AND ocdp1.stock_type = ss.upload_stock_type
         LEFT OUTER JOIN mdata_origin_channel_default_port ocdp2 ON ocdp2.origin = ti.origin
                                                                AND ocdp2.stock_type = ''
    WHERE Date_Loaded = @MaxDateLoaded
      AND (conv_zgport_ship = 'NULL'
        OR conv_zgport_ship = NULL)
    OPTION (MAXDOP 4);

    SET @Rowcountcnzg = @Rowcountcnzg + 1;
END;
```

How i calculate batch Size

```
DECLARE @Rowcount INT = 0;    
  DECLARE @rowstr nvarchar(100);    
  DECLARE @BatchSize INT = 500000;    
  DECLARE @CountECC INT = ( Select CASE when Count(*) >= 100000 THEN count(*)/@BatchSize     
           When (Count(*) > 10000  and Count(*) < 100000)  THEN count(*)/10000       
           ELSE count(*) END     
         FROM i_hold_sap_stock WITH (NOLOCK) JOIN mdata_mixing_unit mu    
           WITH (NOLOCK) ON (SELECT max(output_code)     
              FROM [dbo].[map_codes] WITH(NOLOCK)    
              WHERE UPPER(input_code) = UPPER(upload_mixing_unit)    
              AND UPPER(mapping_type) = UPPER( 'STOCK_PLANTTOMIX')    
              AND site_id = 0    
              AND UPPER(fa_area) = UPPER('TEACONNECT')) = mu.mixing_unit WHERE Date_Loaded=@MaxDateLoaded)    

   WHILE (@Rowcount < (@CountECC+1))       
   BEGIN    
    UPDATE TOP (@BatchSize) i_hold_sap_stock SET conv_mixing_unit = mu.mixing_unit,site_id = mu.site_id    
    FROM i_hold_sap_stock WITH (NOLOCK)    
    INNER JOIN mdata_mixing_unit mu WITH (NOLOCK)    
    ON (SELECT max(output_code)    
      FROM [dbo].[map_codes] WITH(NOLOCK)    
       WHERE UPPER(input_code) = UPPER(upload_mixing_unit)    
      AND UPPER(mapping_type) = UPPER( 'STOCK_PLANTTOMIX')    
      AND site_id = 0    
      AND UPPER(fa_area) = UPPER('TEACONNECT')    
     ) = mu.mixing_unit    
    WHERE Date_Loaded=@MaxDateLoaded        
    OPTION(MAXDOP 4)    
    SET @Rowcount = @Rowcount+1;     
    SET @rowstr = CAST(@Rowcount as nvarchar)     
    RAISERROR(@rowstr, 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT     
   END
```

This is my query don't why its taking too much time to execute. In one SP there are lot of SP But in this SP i am getting more time what should i modify in this please guide me.

Comment: The first thing you need to get ride of is the `WHILE` loop.

Comment: what should i write in place of while ??

Comment: Do you have indexes on the tables and columns that are inner joined?

Comment: @Sami looks like the statement is batching, as it has `UPDATE TOP (@BatchSize)`. Would be interesting to know what the batch sizes are. But within the `WHILE`, only `@Rowcountcnzg` is referenced, and that isn't in the `UPDATE` statement at all, which makes me think it's going to loop infinitely. Sample data, expected results will help us here.

Comment: @Rowcountcnzg initially i have declare as 0

Comment: I asked about what the size of `@BatchSize` was though, @NitsPatil . Also, again, you don't reference `@Rowcountcnzg` in the `UPDATE` statement at all, so I'm pretty sure it'll infinitely loop.

Comment: Please my updated code

Comment: Check line no 6 in your first code. I think it should be ELSE COUNT(*)/COUNT(*). You are making batches for records greater than 10000, but say if your records are 9999, then your loop goes for 9999 iterations unnecesarilly.

Comment: Gah! now you have an `UPDATE` while using a `NOLOCK`!!! That's a terrifying prospect. [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Comment: so i need to change 10000   to 9999 ??

Comment: @bad habits please reply

Comment: @Larnu Please guide me

Comment: Guide you to what. You haven't answered any of the comments I made...

Comment: @Larnu while calculating zgport_ship  query taking too long time why ??? i replace while loop with If but still its taking too long time .. please guide me i know you can solve my problem bcz many times i got ans from you

Comment: I can't answer a question when i don't know the goal, which you've still not told us, @NitsPatel ... I also can't answer a question that is closed, because of a lack of description of a goal.

Comment: @Larnu what you want to know more in this query

Comment: See my prior [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60720769/query-is-taking-a-long-time-to-execute?noredirect=1#comment107431826_60720769) I made over an hour ago.

Comment: @Larnu i have posted query for calculating batch size calculation

Comment: @Larnu would you please explain me how to avoid infinity loop. what should i write in  UPDATE TOP (BatchSize)  ss i am updating and size of Batchsize  is 500000.

Comment: @Larnu i got thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below query

You are making batches for records greater than 10000, but say if your records are 9999, then your loop goes for 9999 iterations unnecesarilly.

```
declare @countRecords bigint=(SELECT count(*)       
                             FROM i_hold_sap_stock ss WITH (NOLOCK)
                                  JOIN tea_item ti ON ss.upload_tea_item = ti.tea_item
                                                  AND ss.upload_revision = ti.revision
                                  LEFT OUTER JOIN mdata_origin_channel_default_port ocdp1 ON ocdp1.origin = ti.origin
                                                                                         AND ocdp1.stock_type = ss.upload_stock_type
                                  LEFT OUTER JOIN mdata_origin_channel_default_port ocdp2 ON ocdp2.origin = ti.origin
                                                                                         AND ocdp2.stock_type = ''
                             WHERE Date_Loaded = @MaxDateLoaded
                               AND conv_zgport_ship = 'NULL');



DECLARE @Rowcountcnzg int = 0;
DECLARE @countcnzg bigint = (SELECT CASE
                                         WHEN @countRecords >= 100000 THEN @countRecords / @BatchSize
                                         WHEN (@countRecords > 10000
                                           AND @countRecords < 100000) THEN @countRecords / 10000
                                         ELSE @countRecords/@countRecords END)

IF(@countRecords<10000)
set @BatchSize=@countRecords

WHILE (@Rowcountcnzg < @countcnzg + 1)
BEGIN

    UPDATE TOP (@BatchSize)
        ss
    SET conv_zgport_ship = ISNULL(ISNULL(ocdp1.default_origin_location, ocdp2.default_origin_location), 'NULL')
    FROM i_hold_sap_stock ss
         JOIN tea_item ti ON ss.upload_tea_item = ti.tea_item
                         AND ss.upload_revision = ti.revision
         LEFT OUTER JOIN mdata_origin_channel_default_port ocdp1 ON ocdp1.origin = ti.origin
                                                                AND ocdp1.stock_type = ss.upload_stock_type
         LEFT OUTER JOIN mdata_origin_channel_default_port ocdp2 ON ocdp2.origin = ti.origin
                                                                AND ocdp2.stock_type = ''
    WHERE Date_Loaded = @MaxDateLoaded
      AND (conv_zgport_ship = 'NULL'
        OR conv_zgport_ship = NULL)
    OPTION (MAXDOP 4);

    SET @Rowcountcnzg = @Rowcountcnzg + 1;
END;
```

Comment: if suppoesed countRecords value will be gratter then 10000 then it will not work right??

Comment: but right now its working as you mention but make sure for more then 10000 it will work or not

Comment: @NitsPatel It will work for any number of records, I have made it dynamic.

Comment: I have made it dynamic how please explain me bit if possible because as i see IF(@countRecords<10000) so..